How to plot weather data using Earthkit-plot
I am also working on a weather project for that I must extract some weather data out of GRIB file folks say it's gridded binary file where the data about whatever whether parameter is provided to you in the form of grids. I have successfully extracted the data but now I need to plot them and generate an image.
I heard there is a sub package of Earthkit called earthkit-plots (https://earthkit-plots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
I am thinking of using that to do the task. Problem I am facing is the package has a very unclear documentation which makes matter worse given I am beginner in Python too.
If anyone wants to take a look at the code here it is.
import earthkit.data
import numpy as np




def get_data_indices(lat_min, lon_min, lat_max, lon_max):
    lat_min_idx = np.abs(lat_data - lat_max).argmin()
    lat_max_idx = np.abs(lat_data - lat_min).argmin()
    lon_min_idx = np.abs(lon_data - lon_min).argmin()
    lon_max_idx = np.abs(lon_data - lon_max).argmin()
    
    # Ensure indices are within bounds
    lat_min_idx = max(0, min(lat_min_idx, len(lat_data) - 1))
    lat_max_idx = max(0, min(lat_max_idx, len(lat_data) - 1))
    lon_min_idx = max(0, min(lon_min_idx, len(lon_data) - 1))
    lon_max_idx = max(0, min(lon_max_idx, len(lon_data) - 1))
    
    return lat_min_idx, lat_max_idx, lon_min_idx, lon_max_idx
    

data = earthkit.data.from_source("file", "wind_data.grib2")
u = data.sel(param="t", level=50)[0] # my collegue told u is the wind parameter or something

u_data = u.data()

lat_data = u_data[0, :, 0]
lon_data = u_data[1, 0, :]
wind_data = u_data[2]

lat_min_idx, lat_max_idx, lon_min_idx, lon_max_idx = get_data_indices(lat_min, lon_min, lat_max, lon_max)

region_wind_data = wind_data[lat_min_idx:lat_max_idx + 1, lon_min_idx:lon_max_idx + 1]


